# Geom line plotting with gradient intensity based peak concentrations

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I have some data of "heartbeats" - measured in amps - (let's say) that beat over a period of time (seconds). Here are some lines:

```
 time                    amps
 5.32632    0.0291289784
   5.334    0.0271881307
 5.33424    0.0463933055
 5.33624    0.0149292168
 5.33888    0.0668341603
 5.33924    0.0384420334
  5.3402    0.028831443
 5.34036    0.0386542207
 5.34052    0.0146365606
 5.34136    0.0374055127
  5.3414    0.0544995649
 5.34168    0.0342488711
 5.34184    0.0197212594
 5.34212    0.2039598122
 5.34232    0.0565000587
 5.34236    0.0332496556
 5.34256    0.0346007892
  5.3426    0.0325735156
   5.343    0.0317928565
  5.34316   0.034084553
  5.3438    0.0875207643
 5.34436    0.0356283179
 5.34452    0.0306993392
 5.34456    0.0288807644
  5.3448    0.0165046742
 5.34504    0.0282299051
  5.3452    0.0533351795
  5.3458    0.05287876
   5.346    0.1192851075
   5.346    0.0318748452
 5.34648    0.022514099
  5.34652   0.0295305232
```

These heart beats will peak at a certain frequency, and different intensities that are followed by moments of rest. I'm attaching, a plot I made with ggplot, that shows all the data.

My question: I want to make a color gradient (visually in ggplot) based on peak clusters. So, the more peaks that are clustered together the darker they appear in the plot. The areas of fewer clusters appear lighter. And also a key the top right/left corner with this gradient would be nice.

I used geom_line to make the plot below here's my code:

```
beats <- read.csv("beat_intesity.csv")
p <- ggplot(beats, aes(x=time, y=amps))
p + geom_line()
```

[image: beat intensity]

You can see some regions have more peaks than others. I'm not sure if this is a very easy problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The simplest approach is to construct some variable `z` that measures the peak intensity and then use `aes(colour = z)`. If you'd like to see the complete answer, please make a reproducible example.

Comment: Please don't post duplicates: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/145809/7828 Also, please try harder yourself before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a gradient plot based on cluster densities in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577029/creating-a-gradient-plot-based-on-cluster-densities-in-r)

Comment: @tonytonov I've pasted some more data, can you show me what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

The simplest measure of intensity I can think of is running average:

```
ma <- function(x, n=5){as.numeric(filter(x, rep(1, n), sides=2))}
```

Take a reasonable threshold, say `0.1`.

```
beats$peaks <- ma(beats$amps > 0.1)
```

Map the resulting variable to colour.

```
ggplot(beats, aes(x=time, y=amps, color=peaks)) + geom_line()
```

Play around with `scale_colour_gradient` to choose the desired colour palette.